# Order result by count of common array elements

Tags: postgresql, array

Using Postgres 9.4, I'm interested in having an array of integers like `user_ids_who_like` and provide an array of users (like `user_ids_i_am_following`) to sort that intersection.

Something like:

```
select * 
from items 
where [there is an intersection between 
       user_ids_who_like with user_ids_i_am_following] 
order by intersection(user_ids_who_like).count
```

Is grouping and ordering by an array intersection possible?

Example data:

```
items
name          | user_ids_who_like
'birds'       | '{1,3,5,8}'
'planes'      | '{2,3,4,11}'
'spaceships'  | '{3,4,6}'
```

For a given `user_ids_who_i_follow = [3,4,11]`, can I do something like:

```
select * from items
where <user_ids_who_like intersects with user_ids_who_i_follow>
order by <count of that intersection>
```

Desired result:

```
name          | user_ids_who_like  | count
'planes'      |  '{2,3,4,11}'      | 3
'spaceships'  |  '{3,4,6}'         | 2
'birds'       |  '{1,3,5,8}'       | 1
```

One possibility seems to be something like this:

```
select id, user_ids_who_like, (user_ids_who_like & '{514, 515}'::int[]) as jt  
from queryables 
where user_ids_who_like && '{514, 515}' 
order by icount(user_ids_who_like & '{514, 515}'::int[]) desc;
```

But I can't tell if this style (using the intarray extension rather than native array functions and operators) is outdated; any feedback from more sophisticated users here? It's not clear to me how to do the intersection of two arrays using the [methods and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html).

Comment: `intarray` still has its use cases, this might be one of them.  The extension has a few funtions, too, which are very handy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With tools of the basic Postgres installation only, you might `unnest()` and count in a `LATERAL` subquery:

```
SELECT i.name, i.user_ids_who_like, x.ct
FROM   items i
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct
   FROM   unnest(i.user_ids_who_like) uid
   WHERE  uid = ANY('{3,4,11}'::int[])
   ) x
ORDER  BY x.ct DESC;  -- add PK as tiebreaker for stable sort order
```

We don't need a `LEFT JOIN` to preserve rows without match because `count()` always returns a row - 0 for "no match".

#### [`intarray`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html)

Assuming `integer` arrays **without NULL values or duplicates**, the [intersection operator **`&`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/intarray.html#INTARRAY-OP-TABLE) of the `intarray` module would be much simpler:

```
SELECT name, user_ids_who_like
     , array_length(user_ids_who_like & '{3,4,11}', 1) AS ct
FROM   items
ORDER  BY 3 DESC NULLS LAST;
```

I added `NULLS LAST` to sort empty arrays last - after the reminder from your later question:

- [How to get 0 as array_length() result when there are no elements](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124741/how-to-get-0-as-array-length-result-when-there-are-no-elements)

[Install `intarray` once per database for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10868144/939860)

Use the [overlap opertaor **`&&`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html#INTARRAY-OP-TABLE) in the `WHERE` clause to rule out rows without any overlap:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   ...
WHERE user_ids_who_like && '{3,4,11}'
ORDER  BY ...
```

Why? [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html#AEN160418)

> `intarray` provides index support for the `&&`, `@>`, `<@`, and `@@` operators,
>   as well as regular array equality.

Applies to standard array operators in a similar fashion. Details:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29245753/939860)

---

Alternatively and more radically, a [normalized schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) with a separate table instead of the array column `user_ids_who_like` would occupy more disk space, but offer simple solutions with plain btree indexes for these problems.