# How to get 0 as array_length() result when there are no elements

Tags: postgresql, order-by, null, array

I have a query like this:

```
select id, array_length(users_who_like_ids,1) as ct
from queryables
order by 2 desc;
```

But empty arrays (with no elements) sort on top. I'd rather have `array_length()` return 0 for that case so that this would get sorted to the bottom.

I'm probably not understanding `array_length()` (ok, definitely) but:

```
embers_dev2=# select array_length(array[1,2], 1), array_length(ARRAY[]::integer[],1);
```

[image]

should return 0 rather than nothing (NULL), right?

Could I do an if statement like inline on it?

### Edit

According to this related answer on SO, it looks like `COALESCE` might be what I want - but I am open to better ideas:

- [postgresql return 0 if returned value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007056/939860)

Comment: Related previous question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/122187/3684

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> should return 0 rather than nothing (NULL), right?

It's up for debate what this *should* return. But the way Postgres defines it, the result for any dimension that does not exist is NULL.

[`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) is the tool to fix your query, but the better solution is not to break it to begin with.

#### Alternative in Postgres 9.4

Postgres 9.4 or later provides a separate function **`cardinality()`** that [per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

> returns the total number of elements in the array, or **0 if the array is empty**

Bold emphasis mine.
Seems like you deal with 1-dimensional arrays exclusively and just want to use *that*.

```
test=# SELECT cardinality('{}'::int[]);
 cardinality
-------------
           0
```

However, this is not the proper fix for your problem, yet. The whole array might be NULL, which returns NULL either way and still sorts on top.

#### Fix query with `NULLS LAST`

```
SELECT id, array_length(users_who_like_ids, 1) AS ct
FROM   queryables
ORDER  BY 2 DESC NULLS LAST;
```

- [Why do NULL values come first when ordering DESC in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20959470/939860)

This *always* deals with NULL values properly. You might still want to use `cardinality()` to sort empty arrays before NULL. But be aware of the difference when dealing with multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: I updated my answer to your previous question accordingly: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122511/3684. Note that the first query there avoids a similar problem because the aggregate function `count()` never returns NULL.

Comment: thx Erwin for excellent answer (again) - will definitely go with NULLS LAST and hopefully be doing multi-dimensional arrays and JSON soon; really enjoying Postgres