# array_length if array is empty behaviour

Tags: postgresql, array

Please explain to me this behavior.

This SQL finds elements where ids (type is `array::bigint`) is empty.

```
SELECT * FROM rises WHERE ids = '{}'
-- finds, e.g., 9 rows
```

This SQL finds no rows:

```
SELECT * FROM rises WHERE array_length(ids, 1) = 0
--finds always 0 rows
```

But this SQL can find non-empty arrays

```
SELECT * FROM rises WHERE array_length(ids, 1) > 0
--finds, e.g., 15 rows
```

Initialization:

```
CREATE TABLE rises(
    id bigserial, 
    d1 bigint DEFAULT 0, 
    ids bigint[] DEFAULT '{}', 
    PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Why `array_length` can find non-empty arrays but it doesn't work for empty arrays?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like PostgreSQL returns `NULL` for empty arrays. Try:

```
SELECT 
    array_length(ARRAY[]::bigint[], 1),
    array_length(ARRAY[]::bigint[], 1) IS NULL,
    array_lower(ARRAY[]::bigint[], 1),
    array_upper(ARRAY[]::bigint[], 1)
```

You get:
`null|true|null|null`

Looks weird, but that's just the way it is. The workaround is to use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(array_length(ARRAY[]::bigint[], 1), 0)
```

returns 0.

Tried this on PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: The `CARDINALITY(array)` function added in 9.4 is a good option. Per https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124745/159595